# accessing an executable in a path using windows OS to use SCIP solver?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, operating-system, backend, google-colaboratory

I am solving an optimization problem and I have the executable file of the SCIP solver in which I want to use. It is located in my windows local computer, but I want to use it to solve a problem where the script is running in google colab.

My path for the solver in my local computer is: "C:\Users\acbba\Desktop\optimization\scipampl-6.0.0.win.x86_64.intel.opt.spx2.exe".

For example, when I want to use IPOPT solver the line of codes are:

```
#IPOPT solver (NLP):
!wget -N -q "https://matematica.unipv.it/gualandi/solvers/ipopt-linux64.zip"
!unzip -o -q ipopt-linux64
solver = SolverFactory('ipopt', executable='/content/ipopt')#.solve(model).write()
solver.options['max_iter'] = 3500 # standard is 3000
solver.solve(model).write()
```

In the case above I am accessing an external server and installing it into my online colab section. But in my case, I have to access the executable in my local computer.

What should be the lines of code that I have to use to make it work properly? (acessing my executable).

Should it be:?

```
solver = SolverFactory('scip', executable='C:\Users\acbba\Desktop\optimization\scipampl-6.0.0.win.x86_64.intel.opt.spx2.exe')
```

But how to access my local computer within drive? Is it using OS path?
Could anyone help?
Thanks